# Craft 4: How to programmatically attach fields to entry type tab

Tags: plugin-development, upgrades, craft4

I'm in the process of upgrading a plugin from Craft 3 to Craft 4.
When the plugin is installed it creates some fields and attaches them to an entry type.
The way it was done in Craft 3 is:

1. Get the Section
2. Get the first Entry Type for said Section
3. Get Field Layout for said Entry Type
4. Get Tabs for said Field Layout
5. Assign fields to First Tab.
6. Assign updated Tab to Layout
7. Assign Field Layout to Entry Type
8. Save Entry Type

Code:

```
    $section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle(Handles::CHANNEL);
    $entryType = $section->getEntryTypes()[0];
    $layout = $entryType->getFieldLayout();

    $tabs = $layout->getTabs();

    $tabs[0]->setFields(array_merge($tabs[0]->getFields(), $fields));

    $layout->setTabs($tabs);

    $entryType->setFieldLayout($layout);

    Craft::$app->sections->saveEntryType($entryType);
```

This fails on Craft 4, because the `FieldLayoutTab` class no longer has a `setFields` method (nor a `getFields` method, which was replaced with a `fields` method).

What would be the correct way to attach existing Fields to Tab in Craft 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. You can use `getElements` and `setElements` instead.

This is for a category though:

```php
    use craft\fieldlayoutelements\CustomField;

    public function safeUp(): bool
    {
        $field = Craft::$app->fields->getFieldByHandle('sortedProducts');
        $catGroup = Craft::$app->categories->getGroupByHandle('artworkCategories');
        $layout = $catGroup->getFieldLayout();
        $tabs = $layout->getTabs();

        foreach ($tabs[0]->elements as $i => $element) {
            if ($element instanceof CustomField && $element->getField()->handle === 'sortedProducts') {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $newElement = [
            'type' => CustomField::class,
            'fieldUid' => $field->uid,
            'required' => false,
        ];

        $tabs[0]->setElements(array_merge($tabs[0]->getElements(), [$newElement]));
        $layout->setTabs($tabs);
        Craft::$app->fields->saveLayout($layout);

        return true;
    }
```